# Using mgo with context

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have been using mgo for my API but I'm seeing many current connections in my MongoDB (while using less than 5 devices for testing). By executing `db.serverStatus().connections` in my Mongo server I get: `{ "current" : 641, "available" : 838219, "totalCreated" : 1136 }`. Below I transcript my issue in mgo's Github ([Issue #429](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/429)):

Is my way of using mgo in a web server the correct way? If not, can you give me a full example?

This code is not functional, take it as almost pseudo code (because of the missing parts like the imports or where the configs come from and models), but it is exactly how I am using mgo.

**I must clarify that I'm building an API which is used by several mobile devices and webapps.**

main.go

```
func main() {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{config.DatabaseURL},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: config.DatabaseName,
        Username: config.DatabaseUsername,
        Password: config.DatabasePassword,
    }

    db, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot Dial Mongo: ", err)
    }

    defer db.Close() 
    db.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    phoneIndex := mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"pp"},
        Unique:     true,
        DropDups:   true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     true,
    }

    err = db.DB(config.DatabaseName).C("users").EnsureIndex(phoneIndex)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/login", publicWithDB(login, db)).Methods("POST")

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func publicWithDB(fn http.HandlerFunc, db *mgo.Session) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        dbsession := db.Copy()
        defer dbsession.Close()
        fn(w, r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), contextKeyDatabase, dbsession)))
    }
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm() // Parses the request body
    device := r.Form.Get("device")

    var deviceid bson.ObjectId
    if bson.IsObjectIdHex(device) {
        deviceid = bson.ObjectIdHex(device)
    }

    db := r.Context().Value(contextKeyDatabase).(*mgo.Session)

    var device models.Device
    err := db.DB(config.DatabaseName).C("devices").FindId(deviceid).One(&device)

    w.WriteHeader(200)
    w.Write([]byte(utils.ResponseToString(models.Response{Status: 200, Message: "asdasd", Data: device})))

}
```

I'm posting this because I couldn't find a complete implementation.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why you would have so many connections, but I would not be passing around a db connection through the request context. It's not request specific, and you can't mock that for testing purposes.

Comment: @Gavin ok, I understand what you mean, so I will remove it from my request context and make it like a global variable, then I would just simply do a `db.Copy()` from that db. Would that be right?

Comment: What I have seen most people do, and what I tend to do myself, is store it on a struct wrapping your db or representing a specific repository. Then you can use an interface, allowing you to pass in said object or a mock object.

Comment: @Gavin could you give me an example in an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how I have seen myself and others structure web apps in Go. This code is untested and is purely for example. It's missing imports and potentially has errors.

**EDIT** Added a middleware example.

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{config.DatabaseURL},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: config.DatabaseName,
        Username: config.DatabaseUsername,
        Password: config.DatabasePassword,
    }

    db, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot Dial Mongo: ", err)
    }

    defer db.Close() 
    db.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    phoneIndex := mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"pp"},
        Unique:     true,
        DropDups:   true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     true,
    }

    err = db.DB(config.DatabaseName).C("users").EnsureIndex(phoneIndex)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mgoAdapter := mongo.NewAdapter(db, config.DatabaseName)
    deviceStore := mongo.NewDeviceStore(mgoAdapter)
    userStore := mongo.NewUserStore(mgoAdapter)

    loginController := controllers.NewLoginController(deviceStore)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/login", middleware.AuthorizeUser(userStore)(http.HandlerFunc(loginController.Login)).Methods("POST")

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

controllers/login.go

```
package controllers

type LoginController struct { 
    store DeviceStore
}

func NewLoginController(store stores.DeviceStore) *LoginController {
    return &LoginController{
        store: store,
    }
}

func (c *LoginController) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm() // Parses the request body
    device := r.Form.Get("device")
    data, err := c.store.FindByDevice(device)

    var respose models.Response
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        response = models.Response{Status: 500, Message: fmt.Sprintf("error: %s", err)}
    } else if data == nil {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        response = models.Response{Status: 404, Message: "device not found"}
    } else {
        response = models.Response{Status: 200, Message: "device found", Data: data}
    }

    // Write sets header to 200 if it hasn't been set already
    w.Write([]byte(utils.ResponseToString(response)))
}
```

stores/stores.go

```
package stores

type DeviceStore interface {
    FindByDevice(device string) (*models.Device, error)
}

type UserStore interface {
    FindByToken(token string) (*models.User, error)
}
```

middleware/auth.go

```
package middleware

func AuthorizeUser(store stores.UserStore) func(h *http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h *http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Logic for authorizing user
            // Could also store user in the request context
        })
    }
}
```

mongo/mongo.go

```
package mongo

type Adapter struct {
    session      *mgo.Session
    databaseName string
}

func NewAdapter(session *mgo.Session, dbName string) *Adapter {
    return &Adapter{session: session, databaseName: dbName}
}

type deviceStore struct {
    *Adapter
}

func NewDeviceStore(adapter *Adapter) stores.DeviceStore {
    return &deviceStore{adapter}
}

const devices = "devices"

func (s *deviceStore) FindByDevice(d string) (*models.Device, err) {
    sess := s.session.copy()
    defer sess.close()

    var deviceID bson.ObjectId
    if bson.IsObjectIdHex(d) {
        deviceID = bson.ObjectIdHex(d)
    }

    var device models.Device
    err := db.DB(s.databaseName).C(devices).FindId(deviceID).One(&device)
    if err == mgo.ErrNotFound {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return &device, err
}

type userStore struct {
    *Adapter
}

const users = "users"

func NewUserStore(adapter *Adapter) stores.UserStore {
    return &userStore{adapter}
}

func (s *userStore) GetUserByToken(token string) (*models.User, error) {
    sess := s.session.copy()
    defer sess.close()

    var user models.User
    err := db.DB(s.databaseName).C(users).Find(bson.M{"token": token}).One(&user)
    if err == mgo.ErrNotFound {
        return nil, nil
    }

    return &user, err
}
```

Comment: I've been reading it and already implementing for testing. But what happens if I have a middleware where I have to make use of the db too? I would be opening a connection then closing it, go to the final function and opening a new one and closing it again? Seems weird (but it's currently working)

Comment: @facumedica Sounds weird that you would need to access the database in a middleware chain. Can you give an example?

Comment: I have a middleware in which I check the authorization token of the user. Each user can have multiple tokens that are stored in the db. Just like JWT but I have more control (I can erase it from the db if the user is using the API wrongfully)

Comment: @facumedica Truthfully, I would inject a service into your controller instead of a repository. The service would get a repository injected into it. You could then use your service in the middleware via an interface. However, you could skip the service and just go straight to the middleware with the repository. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment very much, but I think I understand what you mean in the code. Also I really like the idea of storing the user in the context because I realized how many times I ask the database to find a user (insert facepalm). I'll give it a go, thanks man!

Comment: @facumedica No problem, glad to help